# Sentence diagramming

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to make up some handouts on sentence diagramming. For those who didn't have to diagram sentences at school, I'm talking about something like [this](http://gentlyhewstone.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/diagram2.jpg).

[image]

It's basically an exploded view of the sentence, with the various parts all laid out in relation to each other. I would post some sample code for people to comment on, but I'm not even sure where to start with this. I'm putting the `tikz` tag on the question, but I don't even know whether `tikz` is the right tool for the job. Where should I start figuring this out?

(I did find [this earlier post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38229/bracketed-sentences), but it doesn't really get at the branching &c. in the link above.)

Comment: I don't think the linguists' packages are likely to help here - none I've seen, anyway. (But I'm not a linguist.) So probably `tikz` or a similar content-agnostic approach is your only option. Unless someone else knows of something more specialised. The trouble is, there isn't really any *pattern* to the diagram as far as I can tell. Or there is, but it is an irregular and quirky one rather than a standard format.

Comment: That's the thing: there is a system, but it's clunky.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to write a package for this. How hard would that be (in the world of package-writing)?

Comment: Please see revision.

Comment: That you only have one vote (mine) 14 hours into your question is testament, I'm afraid, to how much the subject of grammar is disliked (maybe that and you didn't present an MWE with your question).

Comment: No doubt. Doubly so since (a) Humanities people who use LaTeX are a rare breed and (b) Even in the humanities grammar is a touchy subject these days. I did feel bad about the lack of a MWE, but, as I said, I just didn't even know where to start. The stuff you posted below is a huge help, so thanks.

Comment: While it's possible that many people dislike grammar, I think a more telling reason is that this peculiarly American way of diagramming sentences isn't used in any scientific representation of language; there are better methods for representing structure (such as regular trees) and so interest in this notation for linguists is at best one of a curiosity of times past.

Comment: At the risk of taking us off topic to an extent that breaches SX etiquette, let me ask you: do you think any of those representations would work as a visual aid for teaching teenagers about sentence structure?

Comment: It is peculiarly American but TeX is fairly US-centric in some ways (e.g. geographic origins, hard-coded defaults etc.) so I suspect the fact that these are not used as scientific/technical representations of language is probably the main factor. (While I'm sure there are exceptions, I doubt that many school teachers produce teaching materials in TeX, for example. Perhaps I'm wrong.) And the user base writes the packages for LaTeX so you get what people using it need. Especially, you get what people inclined to upload to CTAN need. (Logicians seem to me less inclined than mathematicians.)

Comment: You are not wrong; in almost fifteen years in the business I've never met another one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TOTALLY REVISED ANSWER:

Macros available to use:

`\startline[indent]` draws the top startline, with optional indent.

`\xdiv` vertical line that crosses the startline, as between "puzzles" and "are" in the MWE.

`\vdiv` vertical line that does not cross the underline, as between "exercising" and "mind" in the MWE.

`\ddiv` diagonal line that does not cross the startline, as between "are" and "games" in the MWE.

`\diag[mode]{diag-dimen}{diagtext}{horiz-dimen}{horiz-text}` drops a diagonal that will vertically extend `diagdimen\baselineskip` downward, places the diag text over it, then draws a line of length `horiz-dimen\baselineskip` and set the horiz-text above it (by default).  If the mode is set to `[d]`, the horizontal line is dashed and the horiz-text is underset, like the word "yet" in the MWE.  If the mode is `[b]`, the diagonal is blanked out, as with the word "exercising" in the MWE.

`\dropleg[mode]{dimen}{left-aligned underset}`  Drops a vertical strut of height `dimen\baselineskip` and then sets the final argument to the right of that.  If `mode` is `[d]`, the strut is dashed, as shown below "are" in the MWE.

`\entry{dimen}{text}{aftercode}` a self-contained underlined entry, such as "and" in the MWE.  The text is centered and underlined by a line of length `dimen\baselineskip`, and the aftercode is executed at the right hand end of the underline.

`\tstrut{dimen}` the trianglular shape with a vertical strut above, as seen below "exercising" in the MWE.  The height of the `\tstrut` object is determined by the number `dimen`, which is a multiple of `\baselineskip`, which should be the difference between the depths of two adjacent `\diag`s.

`\leftstep` the stair-step thingie that is left-lapped.

---

Parameters:

`\rlwd` rule width; (.5pt) default.

`\tlength` the step height and the triangular leg length, both below "exercising" in the MWE; 1.7ex default.

---

In the MWE, you will note that horizontal space had to be added manually between entries.  Also, to create the 2nd line, I left the `\dropleg` below "and" dangling, and used `\vspace` to shift to the lower position.  The argument to `\vspace` (`16\baselineskip`) was easily ascertained, because the `\droplegs` before and after "and" were both of dimen=8.  The `\tstrut` dimen of 2 is also easily ascertained, since the dimen of the "for" `\diag` was 6, while the dimen of "exercising" `\diag` was 4, the difference being 2.

To drop a `\diag` in the middle of a word, you have two options (both shown in the MWE):

1) split the word around the diag, like `newspa\diag{2}{in}{5}{America}pers`, or

2) place the word in a box of smaller width than its actual width, such as `\makebox[3ex]{\textcolor{blue}{puzzles}}\diag{4.5}{crossword}{}{}`.

In either case, you will generally follow the word with some `\hspace`.

Since I could not create a curved arc, the "Appearing" leg is done with a `\dropleg` with a `\diag` as the underset code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
% DASHED LINE OF SPECIFIED LENGTH
% Based on morsburg at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/
% how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-dashed-line/12553#12553
\def\dashfill{\cleaders\hbox to .6em{\rule{1ex}{\rlwd}}\hfill}
\newcommand\dashline[1]{\hbox to #1{\dashfill\hfil}}
%%%%%
\def\rlwd{.5pt}
\def\xdiv{\smash{\rule[-.7071\baselineskip]{\rlwd}{1.5\baselineskip}}}
\def\vdiv{\smash{\rule[-.37\baselineskip]{\rlwd}{1.5\baselineskip}}}
\def\ddiv{\smash{\rotatebox{45}{%
  \rule[-.55\baselineskip]{\rlwd}{1.74\baselineskip}}}}
\newlength\tmplen
\newlength\tlength
\tlength=1.7ex\relax
\newcommand\tstrut[1]{\smash{\raisebox{-.35\baselineskip}{%
  \def\stackalignment{c}\stackon[0pt]{%
  \rotatebox{45}{\rule{\tlength}{\rlwd}}\kern-.2ex%
  \raisebox{.7071\tlength}{\rotatebox{-45}{\rule{\tlength}{\rlwd}}}%
  }{\rule{\rlwd}{\dimexpr #1\baselineskip-.7071\tlength}}}}%
}
\def\leftstep{\smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr-.3\baselineskip-\rlwd}{%
  \llap{\rule[\tlength]{\tlength}{\rlwd}\rule{\rlwd}{\tlength}%
  \rule{\tlength}{\rlwd}~~}}}%
}
\newcommand\dropleg[3][s]{\unskip\smash{%
  \stackunder[\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-.7071pt]{%
    \if d#1%
      \raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\rotatebox{-90}{\dashline{#2\baselineskip}}}%
    \else%
      \rule[\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-.7071pt-#2\baselineskip]{\rlwd}%
      {#2\baselineskip}%
    \fi}{#3}}\ignorespaces%
}
\newcommand\entry[3]{\smash{\makebox[0pt][l]{\def\stackalignment{c}%
  \stackunder[0pt]{\strut#2}{\rule{0#1\baselineskip}{\rlwd}}#3}}%
}
\newcommand\diag[5][s]{\unskip%
  \if b#1\def\dcolor{white}\else\def\dcolor{black}\fi%
  \tmplen=#2\baselineskip%
  \def\stackalignment{l}\def\useanchorwidth{F}%
  \smash{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-.7071pt}{\rotatebox{-45}{%
    \stackon[0pt]{\textcolor{\dcolor}{\rule{1.414\tmplen}{\rlwd}}}{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[1.414\tmplen][l]{~~~~\strut#3}%
      \if d#1%
        \rotatebox{45}{%
          \smash{%
          \kern-.22\baselineskip\raisebox{-.3\baselineskip}{%
            \stackunder[0pt]{\dashline{0#4\baselineskip}}{~~\strut#5}}}%
          }%
      \else%
        \rotatebox{45}{%
          \kern-1.02\baselineskip\raisebox{.52\baselineskip}{%
          \stackon[0pt]{\rule{0#4\baselineskip}{\rlwd}}{~~\strut#5}}}%
      \fi%
    }}%
  }}}}\ignorespaces%
}
\newcommand\startline[1][0in]{\noindent\hspace{#1}%
  \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-#1}{\rlwd}\par%
  \vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip-\dp\strutbox-.7071pt}\par%
  \noindent\hspace{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize\startline
~
\dropleg{2}{%
\diag{5}{Appearing}{3}{
  \diag{2}{in}{6}{
    \diag{3}{most}{}{}
    newspa\diag{2}{in}{5}{America}pers
  }
}}
\hspace{1cm}
\makebox[3ex]{\textcolor{blue}{puzzles}}
\diag{4.5}{crossword}{}{}
\hspace{1.5cm}\xdiv\hspace{2cm}
\makebox[1ex]{\textcolor{red}{are}}
\dropleg[d]{8}{\entry{4}{and}{\dropleg[d]{8}{}}}
\hspace{.8cm}\ddiv\hspace{0.4cm}
\diag[d]{5}{challenging}{2.8}{yet}
\textcolor{black!50!green}{games}
\diag{5}{exciting}{}{}
\hspace{1cm}
\diag{6}{for}{7}{\tstrut{2}}
\hspace{1cm}
\diag[b]{4}{exercising}{5}{\leftstep\vdiv~mi\diag{1.5}{the}{}{}nd}

\vspace{16\baselineskip}
\startline[1in]
~\textcolor{blue}{they}
\hspace{1cm}\xdiv\hspace{1cm}
\diag{2}{}{8}{\diag{3}{literate}{}{}people\diag{3}{with}{5}{patience}}
\hspace{.6cm}
\textcolor{red}{give}
\hspace{.6cm}
\vdiv
\hspace{.6cm}
\textcolor{black!50!green}{joy}
\hspace{.6cm}
\ddiv
\hspace{.6cm}
exquisite
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The traditional format is pretty rigid. I don't know whether adherence to tradition matters, since the whole practice is out of fashion these days, but the basic idea is to create a visual representation of how the words in the sentence relate to each other (so, e.g., the angled line between "are" and "games" means something different from the vertical line between "puzzles" and "are"). I imagine the next step is for me to catalogue all the relationships I would need to depict.

Comment: @crmdgn This is fantastic. I have been looking for something like this for a while to do Greek syntax layouts. I tried to make my own, but failed. Are you planning on making this a package in CTAN?

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the "like".  Since my effort was focused on recreating an image provided by the OP, I don't feel I know enough on the protocols of sentence diagramming to call it a package.  For one thing, what other necessary constructs are required?  For another, I wouldn't know a correct from an incorrect diagram.  With these limitations, I did not want to package it.  But I am glad you find it useful, and would be happy to "support" what is already here, if I am able.

Comment: That feel when the result obtained in the answer is nicer of what the OP wanted to achieve. :D