# Typesetting Dependency Grammar trees

Tags: trees, linguistics, forest

I try to typeset dependency trees:

[image]

Is there a package that does this? It should be compatible with `xelatex`, i.e. not be based on `pstricks`. I could not find anything with google or on CTAN. If there is no package, I would try to do it with `forest`, but this seems not to be straightforward. How can this be done straightforwardly?

**Edit:** I found (half of) a solution in `forest`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}



\forestset{
dg edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word,edge=dotted}{}}},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V
  [N
    [D [the] ]
     [child] ]
  [reads]
  [N
    [D [a] ]
    [book] ] ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

[image]

This gets the dotted lines right and also aligns the words at the baseline. However, the alignment of the nodes is not right. If I could have N exactly on top of book and V above reads and do this in the style definition, this would be the preferred solution. Is there a way to do this in `forest`?

Comment: After 5 minutes on google, I found this [http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Linguistics#Syntactic_trees](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Linguistics#Syntactic_trees).

Comment: `pstricks` is quite compatible with `XeLaTeX` (and even with `pdfLaTeX`, provided you compile with the option `--shell-escape` or `--enable-write18` and load pstricks with the `pdf` option).

Comment: Don't know if this question is related (i.e., an alternate way of showing similar information): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183032/sentence-diagramming

Comment: See also http://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/.

Comment: Thanks for all these hints. I knew most of the packages (I did typeset a text book about grammatical theory), but they do not do what I want. As for `pstricks`, the problem is: If you do a 500 page book, it takes ages to compile the stuff with the shell escapes. I want to get rid of this. I used to use dvips-tree, but this is not compatible with xelatex, so I converted everything to `pstricks`, but as I said, it slows down things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `calign with current edge` option did the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}


\forestset{
dg edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word,edge=dotted,calign with current edge}{}}},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V
  [N
    [D [the] ]
     [child] ]
  [reads]
  [N
    [D [a] ]
    [book] ] ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's the perfect solution!

Answer (score 5):

This is an attempt where `tikz tree` is used. To align the text at the bottom a `dfont` style is defined.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,trees,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{ 
treenode/.style = {inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt, font=\sffamily},
edge from parent/.style={draw, edge from parent path=
    {(\tikzparentnode.south) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}},
dfont/.style={dashed,font=\vphantom{Ag},anchor=north}  % to align the text at the bottom
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 [
% Children and edges style
    level distance=1cm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm},
    level 4/.style={sibling distance=6cm},
    level 5/.style={sibling distance=3cm}
    ]
%% Draw events and edges
 \node (g) [treenode] {are}
            child {node[treenode] (a) {We}}    % left
            child {node[treenode] (b) {trying} % right  
                     child[missing]
            child {node[treenode] (c) {to}
                     child[missing]
            child {node[treenode](d) {understand}
                     child[missing]
            child {node[treenode] (e) {difference}    
                   child {node[treenode](f){the}}
                   child[missing]}
}
}
};  
\node (a1) at ($(a)+(0,-6)$){};
\draw[dfont] (a) -- (a|-a1)node[]{We};
\draw[dfont] (g) -- (g|-a1)node[]{are};
\draw[dfont] (b) -- (b|-a1)node[]{trying};
\draw[dfont] (c) -- (c|-a1)node[]{to};
\draw[dfont] (d) -- (d|-a1)node[]{understand};
\draw[dfont] (f) -- (f|-a1)node[]{the};
\draw[dfont] (e) -- (e|-a1)node[]{difference.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe add `anchor=north` to style of nodes at the bottom?

Answer (score 3):

A bit kludgy, but shows how to specify a custom growth function and a sneaky way of duplicating the words at the bottom. I pinched a couple of styles from from Jesse's answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
% An (incomplete) growth function
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@grow@tree{%
  \tikzset{shift=(270:\tikzleveldistance)}%
  \ifcase\tikznumberofchildren%
  \or     
  \or
     \tikzset{shift=(0:{(\tikznumberofcurrentchild-1)*\tikzsiblingdistance})}
  \else%
     \tikzset{shift=(0:{(\tikznumberofcurrentchild-1-\tikznumberofchildren+2)*\tikzsiblingdistance})}
  \fi
}

\tikzset{%
  dependency tree/.code={\let\tikz@grow=\tikz@grow@tree},
  leaf level/.store in=\tikzleaflevel,
  tree node/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt, font=\sffamily},
     edge from parent/.style={draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}},
  leaf/.style={level distance=(\tikzleaflevel-\the\tikztreelevel)*1cm,
    edge from parent/.append style={dashed}, execute at begin node=\strut}
}
\def\wordnode#1{ node [tree node] {#1} child [leaf] { node {#1} } }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,dependency tree, leaf level=8]

 \node [tree node] 
   {are}
   child { \wordnode{We} }    
   child [leaf] { node {are} }
   child { \wordnode {trying} 
     child { \wordnode {to} 
       child  { \wordnode{understand} 
         child [sibling distance=3cm] { \wordnode{difference}           
           child [xscale=-1, sibling distance=1.5cm] { \wordnode{the}
    }}}}};  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]