# Typesetting Dependency Grammar trees with discontinuous constituents

Tags: trees, linguistics, forest

I managed to typeset simple Dependency Grammar trees ([Typesetting Dependency Grammar trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203418/typesetting-dependency-grammar-trees)), but now want to have non projective graphs. The solution with `forest` is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}



\forestset{
dg edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word,edge=dotted,calign with current edge}{}}},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V
  [N, phantom,no edge
    [L1, phantom,no edge 
      [L2, phantom,no edge 
        [L3, phantom,no edge   [ N,name=nacc [wen\\who] ] ] ] ] ]
  [glaubst\\believes] 
  [N [du\\you] ]
  [Subjunction
    [dass\\that]
    [V-fin
      [V-prt, name=vprt
        [N [ich\\I ] ]
        [gesehen\\seen] ]
      [habe\\have] ] ] ]
\draw (vprt.south)--(nacc.north);
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

This produces the following figure:

[image]

I filled up the empty tree positions with phantom nodes and added `no edge`so that these phantom nodes were not connected. In addition I drew a line from `vprt`to `nacc` by hand.

This is almost it, but I have two questions:

Can this be done better (simpler)?

There is a problem with the alignment of the two Ns. The leftmost N is higher than the right one. Is there a way to put them onto the same line? Is this difference due to the phantoms having no height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `no edge` in addition to `phantom`. You can align the two Ns by using another `tier` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  dg edges/.style={%
    for tree={%
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align=center,
      base=bottom,
      where n children=0{%
        tier=word,
        edge=dotted,
        calign with current edge}{}
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V
  [N, phantom
    [L1, phantom
      [L2, phantom
        [L3, phantom  [N, name=nacc, tier=mytier [wen\\who] ] ] ] ] ]
  [glaubst\\believes]
  [N [du\\you] ]
  [Subjunction
    [dass\\that]
    [V-fin
      [V-prt, name=vprt
        [N, tier=mytier [ich\\I ] ]
        [gesehen\\seen] ]
      [habe\\have] ] ] ]
\draw (vprt.south)--(nacc.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: tweaked tree]

Comment: Very cool! Thanks! With the tier I can drop the phantom nodes alltogether and add a `no edge` to `nacc` instead.