# Forcing a node or a tier to be set below a certain other node in forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, linguistics, forest

Working from [Typesetting Dependency Grammar trees with discontinuous constituents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203868/typesetting-dependency-grammar-trees-with-discontinuous-constituents/) I try to set a graph with two discontinuities.

The first figure does what I want. It has `nacc` and the other N aligned by a `tier` specification and since the second N is a child of V-ptr, it is lower than V-ptr. In the second figure the N corresponding to `ich` is technically a child of the topmost V and hence it is not lower than V-ptr. Is there a way (without phantoms) to get the two Ns or the tier below V-ptr?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}



\forestset{
dg edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word,edge=dotted,calign with current edge}{}}},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V
  [ N,name=nacc,no edge,tier=mytier, [wen\\who] ]
  [glaubst\\believes] 
  [N [du\\you] ]
  [Subjunction
    [dass\\that]
    [V-fin
      [V-prt, name=vprt
        [N,tier=mytier, [ich\\I ] ]
        [gesehen\\seen] ]
      [habe\\have] ] ] ]
\draw (vprt.south)--(nacc.north);
\end{forest}


\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V
  [N,name=nacc,no edge,tier=mytier, [wen\\who] ]
  [glaubst\\believes] 
  [N,name=nich,no edge,tier=mytier, [ich\\I ] ]
  [N [du\\you] ]
  [Subjunction
    [dass\\that]
    [V-fin
      [V-prt, name=vprt
        [gesehen\\seen] ]
      [habe\\have] ] ] ]
\draw (vprt.south)--(nacc.north);
\draw (vprt.south)--(nich.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** One way to achive what I want is to use a phantom daughter of `V-ptr` and couple it with the tier:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
dg edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word,edge=dotted,calign with current edge}{}}},
}


\begin{document}



\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V
  [N,name=nacc,no edge,tier=mytier, [wen\\who] ]
  [glaubst\\believes] 
  [N,name=nich,no edge,tier=mytier, [ich\\I ] ]
  [N [du\\you] ]
  [Subjunction
    [dass\\that]
    [V-fin
      [V-prt, name=vprt
        [down,phantom,tier=mytier]
        [gesehen\\seen] ]
      [habe\\have] ] ] ]
\draw (vprt.south)--(nacc.north);
\draw (vprt.south)--(nich.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I somehow thought that it would be possible to specify that nodes should be below other nodes, that is, using `tikz`syntax to express dominance relations that are not in the tree directly.

Comment: Wow, read 3-4 times and still didn't understand a thing :)

Comment: If I understand you want the first graph in both examples. So, what's the problem just changing the words? May be it's not `formally` correct but, who will look at `forest` source?

Comment: The graphs differ in the position of `ich`. In the first case `ich` is a child of V-prt. In the second case `ich` is a child of the top-most `V`. Since `ich` is a child of `V-ptr` in the first graph, it is typeset below this node. I want to have `ich` below `V-ptr` in the second figure as well and I am looking for a way to express this. So I need something that inserts space between the top-most `V`and the two `N`s for `wen`and `ich`. Or something that pushes the tier `mytier` down to the position it has in the first figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution uses a `phantom` node, and I know Stefan doesn't want it, but I don't know how to align (`tier`) first level children with a fifth level child if this doesn't exist. First example had a reference node but is missing in second one. Of course,I'm open to better solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
dg edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word,edge=dotted,calign with current edge}{}}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V
  [N,name=nacc,no edge,tier=mytier, [wen\\who] ]
  [glaubst\\believes] 
  [N,name=nich,no edge,tier=mytier, [ich\\I ] ]
  [N [du\\you] ]
  [Subjunction
    [dass\\that]
    [V-fin
      [V-prt, name=vprt
       [A, phantom, tier=mytier, [gesehen\\seen, name=seen] ]]
      [habe\\have] ] ] ]
\draw[dotted] (vprt.south)--(seen.north);
\draw (vprt.south)--(nacc.north);
\draw (vprt.south)--(nich.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

**2nd version**

Although with previous version the result was as expected, placing the `phantom` node as `[gesehen\\seen]` parent results in some inconveniences. It's easier if `phantom` node is 
`[gesehen\\seen]'s` brother although aligned with `N` nodes. The phantom node doesn't occupy vertical space and it's not necessary to redraw the edge to `[gesehen\\seen]`. This solution was proposed by Stefan Müller.

```
\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V
  [N,name=nacc,no edge,tier=mytier, [wen\\who] ]
  [glaubst\\believes] 
  [N,name=nich,no edge,tier=mytier, [ich\\I ] ]
  [N [du\\you] ]
  [Subjunction
    [dass\\that]
    [V-fin
      [V-prt, name=vprt
       [A, phantom, tier=mytier]
       [gesehen\\seen] ]
      [habe\\have] ] ] ]
\draw (vprt.south)--(nacc.north);
\draw (vprt.south)--(nich.north);
\end{forest}
```

Both codes result in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did not see your answer before doing my edit of the question (I did not do a propper reload). If one puts the phantom as sister of `gesehen` one does not need the dotted line and one does not have to give `gesehen` a name. Your solution is much better than what I had in the beginning. I used three phantoms as parents of `wen`in order to get everything down below `gesehen`. Thanks again!

Comment: Ignasi would you mind changing the solution towards my edit in the question? I would the mark it as the correct answer and we could close this question.

Comment: @StefanMüller. Did it. Please, feel free to edit my answer if necessary. It's your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. That is, I'm not sure why you want to avoid `phantom` so what the criteria are for an acceptable answer. However, the following does avoid `phantom`. Whether it does anything you consider equally obnoxious, I'm not so sure ;).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
dg edges/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=bottom,where n children=0{tier=word,edge=dotted,calign with current edge}{}}},
}


\begin{document}



\begin{forest}
dg edges
[V
  [N,name=nacc,no edge,tier=mytier, l*=5.5, [wen\\who] ]
  [glaubst\\believes]
  [N,name=nich,no edge,tier=mytier, [ich\\I ] ]
  [N [du\\you] ]
  [Subjunction
    [dass\\that]
    [V-fin
      [V-prt, name=vprt
        [gesehen\\seen]
      ]
      [habe\\have]
    ]
  ]
]
\draw (vprt.south)--(nacc.north);
\draw (vprt.south)--(nich.north);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: tree without phantom]

Comment: I thought of a way to say that the N of `ich` is south west of `V-ptr`, so that tikz puts it on the right level itselve. If this is not possible a phnatom node as daughter of `V-ptr`and the tier connection to it is probably the best way to do it, since this will be as automatic and as font independent as possible. Thanks!